# An API call is not working in Ionic 4 application but working fine in postman

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, postman, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 application which connects to a server and fetches data through API calls. One API which was working fine stopped working in a fine morning. No errors or issues just returns an empty array. The same API is working fine in postman. I have no clue why it is happening..
I have CORS added. Other APIs are working just fine.

API is as simple as this:

```ts
public getUsersLike(value: string) {
  let params = '?username=' + value;
  return this.http.get<SearchUser[]>(this.apiBaseUrl + 'getuserslike' + params, { headers: this.header });
}
```

Comment: can you post your console and send me the response code..there is no reason it should not connect

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Thanks for replying. I figured it out. There was a %20 coming extra coming in the parameter when reading from the input.